# How can I display an image in google app engine?

Tags: python, html, image, google-app-engine

This should be really easy but I am having trouble.

My main.py looks like this:

```
import webapp2
import urllib2
from google.appengine.api import images
from google.appengine.ext import db

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write("hello worldd")
        #********????*********
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Where I have commented `#********????*********` can I place some html headers `<html><head><body><img src>` etc?  When I do this it breaks.

My app.yaml looks like this:

```
application: myprojectnamehere
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

My image is stored in a directory called 'images', in the same project folder as main.py.

Is this automatically uploaded to the server when I hit 'deploy'?

I have found some "clues" on google's website such as [this about general images](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/#Python_Images_and_the_development_server), and [this about dynamic images](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/python/serving_dynamic_images), but I am still having trouble with this.  Can you help bring me up to speed?  I would like eventually to show an image that is a custom button, detect a mouse click on the image, and change the image as a result.

Any guidance would be great.  What I am trying to do should be pretty simple but it's turning out to be much harder than I expected.  From basic searches in the documentation I am finding clues but none seem to be pointing in a clear exact direction for what I need to be using to display a simple image on my app engine webpage.

Next I will familiarize myself with something called the [GWT API](http://www.gwtproject.org/?csw=1), based on a clue I found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/image).

Comment: Two things: you want `http` headers, and yes, you can put the headers in the response, try putting it before you write anything to it. Also: what breaks? can you show us the traceback?

Comment: Also read about how to use [templates](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/gettingstarted/templates.html#tutorials-gettingstarted-templates). I am guessing what you are looking at is related more with how to load your HTML page.

Comment: First you should swap your -/images and your -.* in the app.yaml. When a request comes in it reads top down till it hits something that matches. .* will catch everything so you will never get to your images. I would also recommend following the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld) as it shows you how to set headers then how to use templates.